# Bootstrap Error in WordPress plugin

Tags: plugin-development, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a plugin that generates advanced search queries. All of the UI is done in bootstrap, and the results are displayed via modal (bootstrap.js). On the production site [Greenlane SEO](http://www.greenlaneseo.com/query-generator) I get the JS error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'modal'`. I cannot figure out for the life of me what is causing this as I installed this on [another WP site](http://protechig.com/query-generator) and the plugin works seamlessly (minus the styling).

Comment: You are loading jQuery 1.8.3 and jQuery 1.9.1. That is a good way to get a conflict.

Comment: Hmm, i'll take a look! Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Yea, this is the problem with dime-a-dozen themeforest themes. I am not seeing jquery 1.9.1 in the source though. I'm referring to the Greenlane SEO site which is throwing the errors.

Comment: Yea, I see it now. I commented out the theme's version of jQuery, now more errors are getting thrown, including jQuery not defined, though it's clearly there.

Comment: Okay, I fixed it! Seems I had to queue jQuery again. Works! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading jQuery 1.8.3 and jQuery 1.9.1. 1.8.3 loads from `wp-includes`. 1.9.1 loads from Google. Install JSView on FireFox and right click the page. You will see them. There are two Javascript files, both named `jquery.js`.

You need to work out what is loading those two scripts and make sure that only one jQuery gets loaded, and it will have to be the right one. Hopefully that is the most recent one-- 1.9.1